# Impact of returning const value types in C++11 on move semantics

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, move-semantics

I'm not clear on the impact that returning `const` values has on move semantics in C++11.

Is there any difference between these two functions, which return data members? Is `const` still redundant in C++11?

```
int GetValueA() { return mValueA; }
const int GetValueB() { return mValueB; }
```

What about for these functions?

```
int GetValuesAB() { return mValueA + mValueB; }
const int GetValuesCD() { return mValueC + mValueD; }
```

Comment: no difference cause `int` is a primitive type

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Spot on! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should useless type qualifiers on return types be used, for clarity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579435/should-useless-type-qualifiers-on-return-types-be-used-for-clarity)

Comment: @Alf do you imply that for, say, a `std::string` there would have been a difference? If so, which?

Comment: @Walter: With a string, you could say `foo() += "bar";` only if the return value wasn't const.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to say not in this case, but returning a const of non-primitive type would do a bunch of things...on top of all the const restriction, in c++11 it would effectively disable a [rvalue move constructor](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html).

Comment: @Walter, Another thing with the string is passing and returning the values would be much slower because a full copy constructor will need to be done rather than the move constructor.

Comment: @KerrekSB Hmm. perhaps, but that is not a sensible instruction anyway. The object returned by `foo()` is destroyed after the `+=` operation. So only the side effects of `+=` are not forgotten ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An expression calling a function that returns by value is a prvalue. However, there are no `const` prvalues of non-class non-array type (§5/6):

> If a prvalue initially has the type “cv `T`,” where `T` is a cv-unqualified non-class, non-array type, the type of the expression is adjusted to `T` prior to any further analysis.

This means that there's no difference between your two definitions of the function. Whether it returns a `const int` or just an `int` is irrelevant because the expression is never `const`.

However, there is a difference when you're returning a class type. Consider the following example:

```
struct foo
{
  void bar() { std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl; }
};

foo get_foo();
```

Now, if we call `get_foo()`, we get a temporary `foo` object. This prvalue is not `const` and we can call non-`const` member functions on it, so we could happily do `get_foo().bar()`. However, we can change the declaration of `get_foo` like so:

```
const foo get_foo();
```

Now, the expression `get_foo()` is a `const` prvalue (which is allowed because it is a class type) and we cannot call `bar` on the temporary object returned by it any more.

Nonetheless, it doesn't make sense to talk about move semantics for a non-class type, as an `int` is never moved from. If you return a `const` class type, that can also not be moved from because it is `const`. To demonstrate:

```
foo get_foo();
foo f(get_foo()); // Will call the move constructor

const foo get_foo();
foo f(get_foo()); // Will call the copy constructor
```

This is because a `const` prvalue won't bind to a non-`const` rvalue reference, which is what the move constructor takes as its argument.

Comment: If `void bar()` were `void bar() const` would we be able to call it on the temporary object?

Comment: @M.Dudley Yes, you would. I've just added a little bit about move semantics because I forgot to with my original answer.

Comment: `foo( foo const&& f )` move constructor to the rescue? (just as there is more than 1 copy constructor...)

Comment: @Yakk Then you wouldn't be able to move from `f` because it's `const`.

Comment: `struct foo { mutable std::unique_ptr<int> ptr; foo( const foo&& o ):ptr(std::move(o.ptr)) {};};` pedants to differ.  :)

Comment: @JosephMansfield Depending on what’s required of the moved-from object’s final state, @yakk’s idea works as long as no change to it occurs.