# Should I use const return type in a simple access member function?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I am still not quite sure about the "move semantics". In a simple point class,

```
class point
{

private:

    double xval_, yval_, zval_;


public:
    // Constructs
    // ...


public:

    // Access (return xval_)
    inline const double x() const;

    // Edit
    inline double& x();
};
```

Should I use `inline const double x() const;` or `inline double x() const;` in my Access function?

Comment: Moving `double` is the same as copying it, so this is a poor example. Still, if you are asking about returning `const`, you should at least list some good reasons to do so.

Comment: Does this apply to built-in types? I don't think it does, so your question doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do. If you want client code to be able to modify your private xval_ from outside the class, you want to return `double&`; however, you probably don't want to do that.

Your other two choices are to return a `double` or a `const double`. In this case, they're both the same; you don't get any benefit from adding a `const` in this case, so you should simply return `double` because the `const` is redundant.

```
double x() const;
```

If you had pointers or references, then you might want to consider specifying the `const` for the return type depending on what you wanted to do. For example:

```
const double* xPtr() const;
double* const xPtr() const;
const double* const xPtr() const;
```

Note I did not specify `inline` anywhere. That's a separate discussion that you didn't ask about in your original post. For this example, you can go either way--include it or omit it--the `inline` keyword has nothing to do with your original question.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see a sense to return `const double` from the function,

There could be a sense to define the function as `constexpr` provided that you need to use its result at compile time.

In other cases the return type should be defined as simply double.

Answer (score 1):

When returning by value, it's usually best not to return a const. Reason being: as long as your consumer doesn't change your state, you really don't care what it does with it.
Also, (excluding const cast) the client can always bind to a non-const by copying - but why would you want to force it to do that?

Answer (score 1):

It's good to define const access functions (if you're able), because it allows a user of the class with a const reference to access the value (without having to copy away the const reference).

For the function above, the form:

```
inline const double x();
```

doesn't really make much sense when returning a non-pointer or reference type. Typically you reserve the const modifier when returning a pointer or a reference.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, for built-in types, I don't think it matters. See [Impact of returning const value types in C++11 on move semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745359/impact-of-returning-const-value-types-in-c11-on-move-semantics) for why:

> An expression calling a function that returns by value is a prvalue.
>   However, there are no const prvalues of non-class non-array type
>   (§5/6):
>
> > If a prvalue initially has the type “cv T,” where T is a
> >     cv-unqualified non-class, non-array type, the type of the expression
> >     is adjusted to T prior to any further analysis.
>
> This means that there's no difference between your two definitions of
>   the function. Whether it returns a const int or just an int is
>   irrelevant because the expression is never const.