# Do CV qualifiers affect copy elision of returned objects?

Tags: c++

This is a possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579435/should-useless-type-qualifiers-on-return-types-be-used-for-clarity), but the example under discussion there dealt with a builtin type (`int`). In my current job, I keep getting flagged in code reviews for failing to declare functions like this:

```
std::string getName();
```

as:

```
const std::string getName();
```

The latter seems meaningless to me, but a few of my colleagues feel that the `const` qualifier may afford the compiler a chance to avoid making a copy of the returned value (or some similar optimization). I ran `gcc -s` on this small test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

const std::string name()
{
    return "World";
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, " << name() << '!' << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and the assembly produced is identical if I remove the `const` from the `name()` function. However, my colleagues suggest that the optimization (if any) afforded by the `const` qualifier may be platform-/compiler-specific, so it's better to tack on `const` 'just in case'. I'm reticent to adopt this habit because I haven't managed to find any code in the wild that does this.

So my question is a two-parter:

1. Does the `const` qualifer in the above example make any difference?
2. Would it matter if the returned value were an instance of some `class Foo` instead of `std::string`?

My colleagues are quite reasonable people and are open to the idea that this is a quaint convention that has crept into our code base more-or-less by accident. But nobody is sure enough about this particular usage that they're willing to say it's completely unnecessary.

Comment: You can't move from a `const` variable, that's at least one reason *not* to return `const`.

Comment: [class.copy]/31 allows copy/move elision "when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference (12.2) would be copied/moved to a class object with the same cv-unqualified type" I've had some discussion about the "cv-unqualified" before, but it seems this means that the top-level `const` is ignored for RVO.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if there is any RVO in your example. `std::string myName( name() );` and `const std::string name() { return std::string("World"); }` are examples of RVO as per [class.copy]/31

Comment: If your colleagues claim that this prevents optimizations, how about they show you just a **single real-life example**? (Hint: They won't succeed :) Some people say `const` has other benefits here, but personally I see no reason at all to return `const` values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any (N)RVO in your example. RVO, or copy/move elision, is *allowed* but not mandated in [class.copy]/31. Here are some examples:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A(int i) { std::cout << "ctor\n"; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "dtor\n"; }
    A& operator=(A const&)
    { std::cout << "copy-assignment-op\n"; return *this; }

    // N.B. no default move ctor will be created!
};

A foo() { return 42; }
A bar() { return A(42); }

const A cfoo() { return 42; }
const A cbar() { return A(42); }

int main()
{
    std::cout << "A a(42);\n";
    A a(42);
    std::cout << "\na = foo();\n";
    a = foo();
    std::cout << "\na = bar();\n";
    a = bar();

    std::cout << "\nA b( foo() );\n";
    A b( foo() );
    std::cout << "\nA c( bar() );\n";
    A c( bar() );

    std::cout << "\nA d( cfoo() );\n";
    A d( cfoo() );
    std::cout << "\nA e( cbar() );\n";
    A e( cbar() );

    std::cout << "\ndtors following for a, b, c, d, e\n";
}
```

The output on most recent compilers (on many even at `-O0`) is:

```
A a(42);
ctor

a = foo();
ctor
copy-assignment-op
dtor

a = bar();
ctor
copy-assignment-op
dtor

A b( foo() );
ctor

A c( bar() );
ctor

A d( cfoo() );
ctor

A e( cbar() );
ctor

dtors following for a, b, c, d, e
dtor
dtor
dtor
dtor
dtor
```

As you can see, whether the return type is `const` or not doesn't affect RVO. However, it could, as it isn't mandated. So if you have an old / weird compiler -- test it (or look up in the documentation).

---

There are two kinds of RVO in the example above:

1. copy/move elision of an object with automatic storage duration to the return value (also called NRVO), such as

   ```
   A foo() { A a; return a; }
   ```

   [class.copy]/31 Allows this

   > in a `return` statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a non-volatile automatic object (other than a function or catch-clause parameter) with the same cv-unqualified type as the function return type
2. copy/move elision of a temporary to another object

   ```
   A a( foo() ); // only 1 ctor is called
   A foo() { return A(); } // no copy/move from the temporary to the return value
   ```

   this is allowed

   > when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference (12.2) would be copied/moved to a class object with the same cv-unqualified type

Where "cv-unqualified" (probably) means that the top-level `const` qualified is ignored for this kind of optimization.

Comment: N.B. if your class *does* have a move-assignment-op, returning a const object *prevents* the use of this op in `a = foo();`. So better *do not* return a const object (if it's by-value).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. It seems that a `const`-qualified return value having any affect on a compiler's ability to perform copy elision is a theoretical possibility, since the standard neither mandates nor prohibits this; however, in purely practical terms, it probably makes no difference for any compiler in common use today, and it actually inhibits move optimization in newer compilers. Given that—and the fact that I don't see this idiom practiced in _any_ of projects I follow on the web—I'll continue to avoid it in my own code, at least.

Answer (score 1):

In BOTH of the cases of

```
std::string getName();
```

and

```
const std::string getName();
```

there will be a copy of a string made. However, as long as you write (something like):

```
std::string name;
...
name = getName();
```

it will make ABSOLUTELY no difference if `getName()`'s return type is const or not const, and the compiler will optimise the copy and just copy the internal value inside `getName` directly to the `name` variable without making a temporary copy.

However, if you, instead, return a reference:

```
std::string& getName();
```

or

```
const std::string& getName();
```

it makes a BIG difference, since the first form will let you do:

```
getName() = "Mats";
```

which is probably not what you would WANT the user of the interface to do.

To me, it seems like the reviewers are confusing those two variants.

Comment: "there will be a copy of a string made" For which call / usage case?

Comment: For any usage. Even if you don't use the return value, there will be a return value returned. The RVO is based on simply passing the variable the return value ends up in as the return location, rather than the temporary value that you'd "expect".

Comment: Then you mean that the string literal is copied into a `std::string` object?

Comment: If you have `std::string names[10]; std::string getName() { return names[rand() % 10]; }`, there will be a copy made of the randomly chosen name to store it wherever the returned value from `getName` goes - where that goes depends on how it is used. If you do `std::string fullname = getName() + getLastName();` [where `getLastName()` is similar to `getName()`] then there will be a temporary copy, that is used to concatenate. If you do `std::string name = getName();`, then RVO cuts in, and no temporary is made.

Comment: In your example `return names[rand() % 10];` there's *always* a copy from that array element to the return value. Another copy from the return value to `name` can be elided. Similarly because of rvalue-ref overloads of `operator+`, only two copies occur in `getName() + getLastName()` (from either array element / source element to the return value). For something like `return "hello";` no copy is made (with RVO), only a "copy" of the elements of the string literal to the return value with type `std::string`.

Comment: So, in other words, the string from `getName` does get copied (at least) ONCE in every case. Which is what I said. Exactly when/where that copy is made depends on the circumstances.

Comment: Maybe, I put it in my own words so you could interpret it ;) Semantically, IMO the copy is always at the same spot: from the array element to the return value (temporary). The return value can be identified with another object (-> RVO). (However your `getName()` is different from what the OP does in `name()`.)

Comment: Yes, I'd agree with the semantic description you make. [I just started a new job, and I work with people who get paid to write compiler code - but I'll keep working on the code that gets compiled by the compiler mainly].

Comment: @MatsPetersson, your `std::string fullname = getName() + getLastName();` is _exactly_ the kind of thing we've been discussing at work, thanks.  You and @DyP have convinced me that it makes no practical difference whether `getName()` returns `std::string` or `const std::string`.