# Is the const return type required in both function declaration and definition?

Tags: c++

```
const int test();
int test(){
 return 5;
}

int main(){
 return 0;
}
```

Above does not compile in C++ with this error message:

```
error: ambiguating new declaration of 'int test()'
```

However it does compile fine in C. Knowing these are 2 very different languages, I was wondering if there's a specific feature in C++ which requires it
to have `const` return types in both the definition and declaration?

Comment: Of course. Signatures of function declarations and definitions must match exactly, always. C++ and C ARE different languages. Pretty futile to ask about a comparison or to expect the same compilation results.

Comment: That's not true. Change `const` to `static` and it will compile, static is only needed in declaration.

Comment: Note that in both C and C++, having a return type of `const int` [doesn't really do anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579435/should-useless-type-qualifiers-on-return-types-be-used-for-clarity) and is basically the same as returning `int` except less clear.

Comment: `static` keyword in c++ and c have a totally different meaning, so what?

Comment: I didn't talk about C did I? You said it always has to match in C++ and you're wrong.

Comment: @Dan "However it does compile fine in C." Yes, you did talk about C.

Comment: @Dan `static` isn't part of the type declaration of the return value.

Comment: @Dan Well, meanwhile I have no clue what about you're talking at all :-P

Comment: `Signatures of function declarations and definitions must match exactly, always` No they don't. my static example.

Comment: @Dan `static` isn't part of the function signature, in neither language.

Comment: https://www.cs.unm.edu/~storm/C++/ProgrammingTerms/FunctionSignatures.html says it is.

Comment: @Dan They're wrong then.

Comment: @Dan Your link about function signatures contradicts [Is the return type part of the function signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290038/)

Comment: That link is also using a different meaning of the keyword `static`. `static` means a different thing when applied to member functions of classes than it does when applied to free functions like the one you're asking about. It's a very, very overloaded keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was wondering if there's a specific feature in C++ which requires it
> to have `const` return types in both the definition and declaration?

No. Actually, it's the other way around. There is a specific feature in **C** that drops that requirement.

From [C documentation of function declarations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_declaration#Explanation) @ cppreference.com:

> The return type cannot be cvr-qualified: any qualified return type is adjusted to its unqualified version for the purpose of constructing the function type.

In your C example, even though you think you declared `const int test();`, the `const` qualification is dropped and you actually declared `int test();`. Hence declaration and definition match.

C++ does not drop cv-qualification from return types.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, cv-qualified return type is different from a non-qualified return type, so those declarations conflict.

Note that it isn't ever useful to return a cv-qualified non-class object because the qualifiers will have no effect on the returned value. For classes, it does affect the type of the value and thus affects which member functions can be called (but cv qualified class return types are still rarely useful, if ever).

Comment: Would you be able to provide a small example for classes where it does affect the type of the value?

Comment: @Dan In all cases where the type is a class.

Comment: @alfC The explanation in the answer doesn't cover parameters. The (top level) cv-qualifiers are removed from parameters when forming the function type. (They aren't removed from the return type, as per the answer).

Answer (score -1):

C++ has references.

In C you're always going to get a copy of the return value, so it doesn't matter so much if it's `const` or not.

```
int x;
x = test();
```

In C++ you can capture the return value with a reference, and it makes a big difference if the reference is `const` or not.

```
int &x = test();
const int &y = test();
```

So the compiler needs to know exactly what you're returning.

Comment: `int &x = test();` You can't do that whether function returns `const int` or `int`. references to non-const cannot bind to prvalues. I'm not sure if references are relevant to this question.

Comment: @eerorika they're relevant to why C++ might care more about const correctness than C does.  Wasn't that the question?